# How to validate rows programmatically in react-bootstrap-table2 component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap-table

I am using the [react-bootstrap-table2](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/) component ?

Following is my working of grid:

1. When user clicks the button, it will add one row dynamically.
2. For each column in that row I have written validation function.
3. I have added another button called as "Commit" in one of the column of newly added row, when user clicks that button it should trigger the validation for all the columns of newly added row.

What I have seen is that it triggers validation on blur of cell after edit ?
I am not able to see any way to manually trigger validation (ex. on button click). 
Is there any way to manually trigger validation ?

Comment: You can have a look at this - https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/storybook/index.html?selectedKind=Cell%20Editing&selectedStory=Validation&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybook%2Factions%2Factions-panel

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response but that does not solved my problem that I have mentioned above.

Comment: You shouldn't expect the exact code as solution. Kindly add some code snippets or a sandbox so we understand the problem exactly. Thanks

Comment: @pritam, I used your great example and it works for me. How can I modify the properties of the message (it currently shows on the screen only the last word)?